# Delete overlapping features (select & delete hidden feature below)

Tags: qgis, delete

I have a whole map, with a lot overlapping between features. The first image showed part of the map, with 100% opacity, so the most top features are shown.

[image: Image 1 : Map with 100% opacity]

And in the second image showed the same part, but with 70% opacity, and I see many parts of "hidden" features below them. I already tried the `Check Geometries` to search **duplicates** and **features within features**, some of them deleted, some couldn't (it's said the **features are obsolete**)

[image]

I don't know what to do, but I think the I have to delete the features that hidden below, and I don't know how to select those features.

Comment: It would be great if you could say what the origin of the map is, what kind of map it is, why there are overlapping features, and why you want them removed. Overlapping features does not have to be bad/wrong.